# Library/Spelling does not remember the words I store in it

Tags: mac, spelling

I understand that on Mac I can write words in `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` so the computer remembers this word and stop correcting it.

I added some words to the dictionary but my computer is still correcting them as I write. Any clue what I could do ?

Comment: What is the modification date of that file? Do you have permission to write it?

Comment: Did you restart the computer, or reload applications that make use of the file, after having made changes? Please [edit] and update your question with the additional details requested.

Comment: Which application are you using to write stuff? Have you tried  adding words to the dictionary the usual way? Whenever there's a new word you want the computer to learn, you can "Control-click a word, then choose Learn Spelling. The word won’t be flagged as misspelled in any document." according to the "[Check spelling and grammar on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/mac-help/mchlp2299/13.0/mac/13.0)" Apple support article.

Comment: Which OS version are you on?

Comment: Modification date is jsut after I saved it, I think I have permission.
Restarting does not work either :/

Comment: The file is plain text. Please open it in an editor (such as TextEdit). Does it contain the words you added? Does it contain anything you didn't add?